# Merge Same Cells

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, merge

I am having some difficulty creating a macro to merge the same cells in a table (not actually a table, but you know what I mean). Rather then me try to explain it let me just show you the before and after of what I am trying to do.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

I was able to create a macro for it, but it either screws up my conditional formatting, doesn't properly adjust table numbers, or something of the sort. Anyway, this is what I am trying to do, hopefully someone has an idea of how I can go about solving this.

Also for additional insight, I am using `=Mod(Row(),2) = 0` for white background and `= 1` for grey, not sure if that will not translate properly when merging as I have been having issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with inserting a temporary subtotal column as shown in the gif below. You can also create a dummy column somewhere far on the right of the table. Purpose of the column is to capture blank cells from the newly added subtotal column.
For example, in gif you can create a concatenated column ColF of the table from ColA,B,C of the table. That column can be created on sheet column Z and can be used to subtotal count of that column. The newly added subtotal column then can be used to capture blank cells(as shown in gif column B)

Main benefit is we **don't have to loop through each cell**

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeDupCells()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324153/merge-same-cells
Dim blnkCls As Range, mrgRng As Range, i As Long

Sheet3.Range("B3:B19").Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlCount, _
        TotalList:=Array(1), Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, _
        SummaryBelowData:=True
Set blnkCls = Sheet3.Range("B3:B" & Sheet3.Range("B" & Sheet3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Set mrgRng = blnkCls.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

For i = 1 To Sheet3.Range("B3:B19").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 2
    If i = 4 Or i = 5 Then GoTo next_i
    With mrgRng.Offset(0, i)
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With
next_i:
Next i
blnkCls.Rows.Ungroup
blnkCls.Rows.Ungroup

blnkCls.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).EntireRow.Delete
Sheet3.Range("B:B").EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Last line of the code should be `blnkCls.EntireColumn.Delete`

Comment: Refer [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68756606/9808063)