# How to merge duplicate cell values in rows? My code is ignoring some of the duplicate values

Tags: excel, vba, merge, duplicates, row

I'm trying to merge all contiguous duplicate cells in column D. I don't care about the formatting of the cells, and i don't need to sum any of the values. Was wondering what was wrong with my below code since not all of my duplicate cells are merging...Can only assume i'm skipping over them accidentally

[image: Attempting to merge cells in column D like this. The merge should only be for duplicate values]

```
with thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1") 
For i = StartRow + 1 To LastRow + 1
    
If Cells(i, 4) <> "" Then
    If Cells(i, 4) <> Cells(i - 1, 4) Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Range(Cells(i - 2, 4), Cells(StartMerge, 4)).Merge
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        StartMerge = i
    End If
End If
Next i
End With
```

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324153/merge-same-cells)  helps

Comment: Hi Naresh. this is a bit confusing for me since it seems like the user references blank cells when determining the merge? I'm hoping i can just make my code focus purely on logic similar to if a1 = a2, a2 = a3, a3 <> a4 then a1:a3.merge and then repeat at a4 until the last cell with value. I'm just not really confident in the looping.

Comment: `Range(Cells(i - 2, 4), Cells(StartMerge, 4)).Merge` could be the issue. Where is `StartMerge` given an initial value? Could you just use `i` instead? Also, why `i - 2` instead of `i - 1`?

Comment: sorry about the lack of information! startmerge = startrow which i earlier named as 12. The header starts at d12 and the rows with data start at d13, so i've been fiddling with the numbers..i - 1 would mean the cell before i right? (ex. i - 1 = d12 if i = d13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close to your code:
**(updated; deleted `If Cells(i, 4) <> "" Then`)**

```
Sub test1()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
        StartRow = 1
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        
        StartMerge = StartRow + 1
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For i = StartRow + 1 To LastRow
            If .Cells(i, 4) <> .Cells(i + 1, 4) Then
                .Range(.Cells(StartMerge, 4), .Cells(i, 4)).Merge
                StartMerge = i + 1
            End If
        Next i
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps it is because of the line `If Cells(i, 4) <> "" Then`. See updated version of the code

Comment: Hello! Thank you again. I realized the reason why it was stopping beforehand was because i was using "mergelastrow" to represent the last row for this code. "If Cells(i,4) <> "" Then still works. I accidentally used "lastrow" which represented another last row for another column of data. This works beautifully :)

Answer (score 0):

you can quickly have a view like below with a pivot table.  Just an other idea without coding.  Fyi.

[image: pivot table]

Comment: Thank you for that! Unfortunately i have to merge values so i can group them later.

Answer (score 0):

**Index, Evaluate and filter function** approach to avoid loop through each cell. With these functions, following procedure creates an array of row numbers where a value in a cell does not match with the above cell value.

The array is then looped through to merge the desired "same" cells.

```
Sub MergeSameCells()
Dim ColRng As Range, RowArr
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set ColRng = Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

RowArr = Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Index( _
            Evaluate("IF((" & ColRng.Address & "<>" & ColRng.Offset(1).Address & _
            "),ROW(" & ColRng.Address & "),""NA"")") _
            , 0, 1)), "NA", False, vbTextCompare)
Debug.Print UBound(RowArr)
'result 5, So there will be 6 loops (Zero based array) instead of 13.
For i = UBound(RowArr) To 0 Step -1
    If i = 0 Then
        If RowArr(i) - 1 <> 1 Then
        Range(Cells(2, "B"), Cells(RowArr(i), "B")).Merge
        End If
    Else
        If RowArr(i) - RowArr(i - 1) <> 1 Then
        Range(Cells(RowArr(i - 1) + 1, "B"), Cells(RowArr(i), "B")).Merge
        End If
    End If
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Number of loops won't matter for a small range though.

Comment: Correct. It's only for a small range.